# Flash/AS3: error #1010

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, appendchild

```
59     for (i=0; i < count; i++) //count = number of children
60     {
61        if (localXML.children()[i].Name.toString != firstName ¬
          && localXML.children()[i].Surname.toString != surName ¬
          && localXML.children()[i].Company.toString != companyName)
62        {
63          tempXML.appendChild(localXML.children()[i]);
64        }
65        trace("tempXML: --> "+tempXML);
66        localXML = tempXML; <---- WRONG PLACE!!!
67     }
```

Hello all. I'm getting an error #1010 at line 61.

I did test each value individually and everyone is traced normally. The errors are:

- TypeError: Error #1010: at ... frame9:61
- The script is allways appending localXML.children()[0] and none else.

I can't see any error there. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

SOLVED:

```
59     for (i=0; i < count; i++) //count = number of children
60     {
61        if (localXML.children()[i].Name != firstName ¬
      && localXML.children()[i].Surname != surName ¬
      && localXML.children()[i].Company != companyName)
62        {
63          tempXML.appendChild(localXML.children()[i]);
64        }
65     }
66        trace("tempXML: --> "+tempXML);
67        localXML = tempXML;  <---- MOVED HERE!!!
```

I was updating localXML in with every loop!!! Shame!!!

Answer (score 1):

Check the XML. Either `localXML.children()[i]` is null or `Name` does not exist as a child node on the object.

Also remember that if `Name` is an attribute in the XML, then you need to access it differently.

If the Name is setup like this:

```
<node>
    <Name>Stuff</Name>
</node>
```

Then you access it as you have done so already. But if it is an attribute like so:

```
<node Name="stuff"></node>
```

Then you need to access it like this:

```
localXML.children()[i].@Name
```

Another possible issue is the `children()` call. I've never used it before so I do not know specifically how it behaves. If the above issues do not fix it, try rewriting the parser to skip the `children()` call and just parse it like you normally would with nested loops.

In the end, though Error #1010 means a term is undefined and doesn't exist so you just need to figure out *why* it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot Josh. I did place the update of the main XML (localXML = tempXML) inside the for statement, generating the errors. I was calling the nodes correctly. (I'm not using attributes in this case)